# ASP.NET Core - Running mutiple angular 2 applications

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, model-view-controller, asp.net-core

I'm facing some problems while trying to run multiple angular 2 application with ASP.NET Core. I'm using

> JavaScriptServices with prerendering feature

in a Visual Studio 2015 template.

The structure of my solution is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYTBJ.png).

The *Core* contians the ASP.NET application with server-side routing, and each *ClientApp*, once boundled, is copied inside the *wwwroot*.

The problem here is the *prerendering* feature, which rises:

> *Prerendering failed because of error: Error: Zone already loaded.*

This happens when, after the first render of *ClientApp1* I reload the page or when i try to switch between *ClientApp1* and *ClientApp2*.

Can someone help me suggesting what is proper way to run multiple *Angular2* applications using *boot-server* and *boot-client* style?

Any example/suggestion will be appreciated.

The issue is opened also in github at [github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/issues/566](https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/issues/566)

Answer (score 0):

The approach I'm using that seems to work is to simply define multiple entry points in webpack config.

```
const clientBundleConfig = {
  entry: {
    'front': './client/front/main.ts',
    'admin': './client/admin/main.ts',
  },
  output: {
    path: './www/dist',
    filename: '[name].bundle.js'
  }
  ...
}
```

Now the relevant angular app front or admin will update from a single HMR process. I couldn't get it to work with separate webpack config and HMR processes using the same dotnet server process, I found only the first app would update.

**Update**
I needed to perform a separate build for apps due to restrictions I ran into. I now follow SteveSandersonMS suggestion of calling UseWebpackDevMiddleware for each app in the Github issue you linked to, the only step missing from his suggestion is the need to specify a unique endpoint for each app:

```
app.UseWebpackDevMiddleware(new WebpackDevMiddlewareOptions
{
    HotModuleReplacement = true,
    ConfigFile = "webpack.front.js",
    HotModuleReplacementEndpoint = "/__webpack_hmr_front"
});

app.UseWebpackDevMiddleware(new WebpackDevMiddlewareOptions
{
    HotModuleReplacement = true,
    ConfigFile = "webpack.admin.js",
    HotModuleReplacementEndpoint = "/__webpack_hmr_admin"
});
```